# RCP Application : Could not open the eclipse default editor to open selected file on button click

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rich-client-platform

I am creating RCP application and in that I have to browse file and selected file path is displayed in text box. One button is there to open that selected file. I want to open it in eclipse default editor and I have user listener on button click to open editor. I used below code for opening editor :

```
   IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
   File file = new File("file path from text box");
   try {
        IFileStore fileStore= EFS.getLocalFileSystem().fromLocalFile(file);
        page.openEditor(new FileStoreEditorInput(fileStore), EditorsUI.DEFAULT_TEXT_EDITOR_ID);                 
    } catch (CoreException ce) {
        ce.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But when when I select file and click on open file button then new editor opens but file contents are not shown with following error :

> Could not open the editor: The editor class could not be instantiated. This usually indicates a missing no-arg constructor or that the editor's class name was mistyped in plugin.xml.

In Details section it is giving error(I have copied part of stack trace) :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/resources/IWorkspace
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2493)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2803)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
```

Please help me with this issue to open file(on button click) in Eclipse default editor.

Many Thanks in advance!!

Comment: So it can't find `IWorkspace` - do you have the `org.eclipse.core.resources` plug-in in your RCP?

Comment: Yes, I have already added `org.eclipse.core.resources` plugin.

Comment: Add to where? All plug-ins need to be listed in the .product file (or a feature included in the product)

Comment: I have added in plugin dependencies, I tried to add in .product file but I found `org.eclipse.core.resources.source` and I added it but no success

Comment: Just plugin dependencies is not enough. `org.eclipse.core.resources.source` is the source code - not something you need, it must be `org.eclipse.core.resources`. You must list every plugin that is needed in the product file.

Comment: I have added `org.eclipse.core.resources` and other required plugins as well but still having same issue!

Comment: Are you building the RCP (which uses the product file) or are you running from within Eclipse for testing (run as Eclipse Application)- in which case it is the Run Configuration you need to update.

Comment: I have tried with both way by building RCP and running from within eclipse.

Comment: I tested this code here and it runs without problems, so it has to be the configuration. The Run Configuration has a "Validate Plug-ins" button they may tell you something.

Comment: Validation is saying 'No problems were detected'..

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding default constructor for editor if its a multipage editor